# Excel 2003 - how do I dock\fixate a row\column?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2003

how do I create a docked row\column so that when I scroll down\right, I can still see that row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Freeze Panes" in the Window menu will do this.

To freeze the top row only (to keep your column headings visible), select A2 and freeze panes.

Selecting B2 instead will lock both Row 1 and Column A.

If it doesn't make sense yet, it will as soon as you try it :)

Answer (score 0):

**Additional Help**

[Freeze or Lock Rows and Columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aYdf5.png)

I know that the OP is Asking about Excel 2003, but when I searched for 2010 this is one of the first search results from Google, so I am going to post an answer for ***Excel 2010*** and hope it Helps someone out when they are looking looking for help on this issue as well

I found it Very Difficult to figure out how to do this for the Top row ***and*** for a couple of Columns.
I did figure it out however,

First Split the panes

[image: Excel 2010]

and then move the large black Lines to the rows and columns that you want Static (or Fixed)

you can click `Freeze panes > Freeze Panes` and then click `Split`  or you can just click `Split`. if you do anything else in the `Freeze Panes` and then Try to Split it will only Give you One Thick Black Line.

if your focus is in the are that is Static (Fixed/Locked) and try to scroll you will scroll only that pane.

*I am using Excel 2010*

Comment: Freeze Panes is a better answer than Split Window for the original question. With Split, each section can scroll. With Freeze, the trick is to select the first cell you want to scroll. All cells above and to the left will lock when Freeze Panes is activated.